# How to get the <h:graphicImage> in JSF automatically resize and fit into browsers window?

Tags: html, css, jsf

Given the following snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

<h:head>
 <title>MyTitle</title>
 <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
 <h:graphicImage name="images/MainBackground.jpg"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I'd like the `MainBackground.jpg` to resize automatically. Following css file does **not** resize it:

```
#mainBackground {
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}
```

But if I set the width and height directly in the `h:graphicImage` tag and comment out the `h:outputStyleSheet` like

```
<h:head>
<title>MyTitle</title>
<!--<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/> -->
</h:head>
<h:body>
 <h:graphicImage id="mainBackground" name="images/MainBackground.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

resizing suddenly works. How can I use the external css file working in Java EE context? What is the proper way to do this?

**BTW** I found some tutorials using google and also some questions here on SO regarding embedding an image but all solutions provided either didn't cover resizing or they have not worked for me.

Comment: Are you implying that it works fine when you use `<img src>` instead of `<h:graphicImage name>`? If it also fails with `<img src>`, then it's not a JSF problem and you'd better leave out the JSF noise from the question so HTML/CSS experts can understand you better. Once you get a HTML/CSS based answer, all you need to do is to rewrite JSF code in such way that it produces exactly the desired HTML/CSS output.

Comment: @BalusC Just tried `<img class="mainBackground" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/MainBackground.jpg"
         alt="SomeAlt"/>` and the browser shows me just the alt, no image at all

Comment: ${pageContext} doesn't exist in Facelets, only in its legacy predecesor JSP. Just hardcode the path for sake of testing your assumption.

Comment: @BalusC Nope, still doesn't work

Comment: Then remove as instructed the JSF noise from the question to make it better digestable for HTML/CSS experts. JSF is in the context of this problem merely a HTML/CSS code generator and not the cause by itself. I.e. reframe your question to demonstrate the problem using a plain vanilla `test.html` file instead of a whole server side HTML form based application MVC framework.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, JSF does not output an id for the `h:graphicImage` by default, and if it does, it's most certainly not '`mainBackground`' but usually a nested id like `path:to:image`.

Set the `styleClass` attribute on the `h:graphicImage` and use `.mainBackground` (a CSS class selector), not `#mainBackground` (id selector).  That way you at least get a proper CSS selector.

Furthermore, `auto` is the CSS default for both `width` and `height`, which therefore probably has no effect.  So you most probably want to change that to some actual values.  See some standard CSS reference texts or guides for further details.

Comment: _"IIRC, JSF does not output an id for the h:graphicImage by default, and if it does, it's most certainly not 'mainBackground' but usually a nested id like path:to:image. "_ it supports an id: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/graphicImage.html and the 'path' is dependent of it being in a namingcontainer or not. And if it is, the last part is equal to the id set on the element. And since here it is not in a naming container, it most likely just is `mainBackground`

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for the clarification.